# What is PRC's stance on reforms in the United Nations Security Council?

Tags: china, united-nations, reference-request, unsc

What are the People's Republic of China's thoughts regarding reforms in the UNSC concerning:

- The veto policy of the P5;
- The number of Permanent members; and
- The number of Non-Permanent members?

Good references would be highly appreciated, and China's opinions about the [G4 members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G4_nations) would also be great.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_and_the_United_Nations

Comment: Suggested fourth bullet point: Japan having a larger role in the UNSC.